# ClassCastException Double to Float even when I'm not using a Double

Tags: java, casting

I've spent hours on this bug, this is a very strange behavior for me :

Here is my code :

```
Map<String, Float> myMap = myService.calculateData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);

if (!myMap.isEmpty()) {
    Double value1 = myMap.get("key1").doubleValue(); 
}
```

In the debugger, everything works fine, I can see all the values of `myMap` and I can get the value of `value1` as a Double.

But then, IntelliJ throws the error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: 
>           java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

I tried replacing  `Double value1 = myMap.get("key1").doubleValue();`

with : `Float value1 = myMap.get("key1");`

and I get the exact same error, even though I'm not using any Double !

Also I don't understand why it says Double cannot be cast to Float, when **I'm actually trying to convert a Float into a Double, so it's the other way around**.

UPDATE : to answer to Louis and Andreas suggestions, `myMap.get("key1").getClass()` gives me `Double` , `myMap.get("key1") instanceof Double` equals `true` and `myMap.get("key1") instanceof Float` equals `false`.

I get the error on the line `Double value1 = myMap.get("key1").doubleValue();` or on `Float value1 = myMap.get("key1");`

Comment: *Where* does the exception occur? Maybe in a line you didn't post?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace; `Float value1 = myMap.get("key1");` AFAIK cannot throw that exception.

Comment: That can't be your actual code, as it is not syntactically valid. Please can you post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example by which we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes I also don't understand how `Float value1 = myMap.get("key1");` can throw that exception... this is driving me crazy ! I'll check what happens in `myService.calculateData` and if that doesn't work, I'll post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a normal symptom for some corruption in how the `Map` from `myService.calculateData` was constructed in the first place; it's not *really* a `Map<String, Float>`, it's got `Double`s in it.  That's usually an indication that there were some suppressed unsafe casts or rawtypes.

The cast to `Float` would be implicitly inserted into the `map.get("key1")` call at compile time, as part of how generics are normally implemented.

Comment: Confirm by doing `System.out.println(myMap.get("key1").getClass())`.

Comment: Yes Louis and Andreas, I think you're right because `myMap.get("key1").getClass()` gives me `Double` , `myMap.get("key1") instanceof Double` equals `true` and `myMap.get("key1") instanceof Float` equals `false`. So can the problem be fixed in `myService.calculateData` only ? Not in my code ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman , thanks a lot, the problem was indeed in `myService.calculateData` . You saved me some hours of debugging ! :)